# Laravel clears whole session on logout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I keep different stuff in my session that i use both when user is logged in and logged out. The problem is than when an user logges out then laravel clears everything i store in session:

That happens because laravel core class AuthenticatesUsers looks like this:

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Because i dont want to change a core class how could i avoid losing my session data on user logout?

Comment: You cannot. This is a fundamental principal of sessions.

Comment: A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages. Whether the user is logged in is just a piece of information that may be stored in a session. Doesn't make any sense to flush the whole session just because user logged out.

Comment: @user1985273 Actually it makes sense for the session to be cleared once you logout. Because that data is linked (relevant) to that logged in state, and once you log out you generally want a "clean slate". For example, if I was logged in to a web store and added some stuff to the shopping cart, I would expect when I log out that my cart would be cleared, because if somebody else logged in with another account on the same machine they should not be able to see my cart contents before I logged out. If you want to keep data for a logged in user you should do it using another persistence layer.

Comment: @Bogdan Thats just one example of logged in user data being kept in session. But as i stated session is a way to store information across multiple requests. That data may or may not be related to user being logged in. For example if I have a multilingual website I may want to keep the language a user selects in session, so if user logs out the website will still remain in the language the user selected previously. So clearing all session data on logout still doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Bogdan To get a "clean slate" i would rather keep all logged in user data in a certain session variable that i want to be cleaned on logout. For example $_SESSION['user']['cart'], $_SESSION['user']['whatever'] and clean $_SESSION['user'] on logout. That way you get the "clean slate" and keep data like $_SESSION['selected_language']

Comment: @user1985273 Keeping data like language might be better suited for cookies. The session is stored in a cookie so it ca be persisted across requests, you can store localization and other stuff in a another cookie as well, perhaps by making use of a middleware that automatically handles that (I use that on a regular basis). But if you feel the comfortable approach for you is to not clear the whole session data on logout, then you can override the built in logout method like Muhammad Nauman suggested in his answer. Laravel has its own approach, but it leaves you the option to implement your own.

Answer (score 7):

The default LoginController.php uses the trait AuthenticatesUsers.php .
so copy this code to LoginController.php to overwrite it.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $data =  session()->get('cart');
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    session()->put('cart', $data);
    return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the logout method in login controller would do the trick i guess. write this function in your controller (it is written in AuthenticatesUser trait):

```
/**
* Log the user out of the application.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function logout(Request $request)
{
   $this->guard()->logout();
// session logic here, just pull out things that need to and left other things as it is.

   // $request->session()->invalidate();

   return redirect('/');
}
```

I never did that but I think it might work.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT want to change the code so that your session is NOT invalidated. It happens for a reason. Security.

Instead, create a unique code and store the cart information linked to that code. Then store that code in a cookie for the client. Then each time you see the cookie, you load the cart from the database.

Just DO NOT store any confidential information. What a person wants to buy is not a risk if someone else saw it (not really), so there is no concern in storing it as cookie. Just don't store private information linked to this cookie.